# What's the best algorithm to determine the output location of a string in a HTML?

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing

I'm creating a XSS scanner, now I want to know the output location of a string.

It could be,

- Between HTML tags, e.g `<h2>string</h2>`
- An attribute of a tag, e.g `<h2 class=string></h2>`

Now I need to know which case it belongs to. If I go through all the tags and all their attributes it would be painfully slow, so I need a faster way.

Any suggestion? Running perl

P.S `string` is carefully crafted, which will not cripple the HTML structure in anywhere.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You are looking for the string `string` inside an HTML file? Why not use `grep` or `sed`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem, but here is my attempt at an answer.
This code checks if `$string` is the **only** thing in the attribute/tag, e.g. `<h2>string</h2>` rather than `<h2>hello string</h2>`.

```
print "String '$string' found between HTML tags.\n" if ($file =~ /<(\w+).*?>$string<\/\1>/);
print "String '$string' found in HTML attribute.\n" if ($file =~ /<\w+ (?:.+? )?\w+="$string"(?: .+?)?>/);
```

Note both `print`s will fire if the string occurs in both cases, e.g. `<h2 class=string>string</h2>`.
If you need an explanation of what the regexes do, comment and I'll edit my answer.
This assumes the entire HTML file is in `$file` and the string is in `$string`. The first can be achieved with something like this:

```
$FILE = 'C:/path/to/file.html';

open FILE or die "Cannot open $FILE for read: $!";
while (<FILE>) {
   $file .= $_;
}
close FILE;
```